# Facebook sharing issues in all.js

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using following code to login and share the content to Facebook.

```
.login(function(response) {
  //console.log(response);
        if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log(response);
            testAPI(eventId);
            fbShare();
       }else{
       FB.login();
       }
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
    var fbShare = function() 
    {
    FB.ui({
        method: "feed",
        display: "iframe",
        link: url,
        caption: title,
        description: summary,
        picture: image
    });
};

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {  

FB.init({
  appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ,  
  channelUrl : 'http://ilovesalesevents.in/', 
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true, 
  oauth  : true  ,  // enable OAuth 2.0 // parse XFBML
  version    : 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
});

isLoaded = true;

// Additional initialization code here
  };

     // Load the SDK Asynchronously
     (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));

function testAPI(eventId) {

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     console.log(response);

    if(response.id=="undefined")
         FB.login();

    else{       

    } 
      // console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
}
```

I can able to login in Facebook,After login in console i am getting the error
[image: screenshot]

Comment: aren´t you missing some code? this looks weird: ".login...."

Comment: btw, that whole code is weird, you should ONLY use FB.ui on mouse interaction, never in an asynchronous callback function. also, you don´t need any permission (or login) for FB.ui dialogs. not sure why you are asking for publish_actions.

Comment: take a look at this, read it carefully and make sure you understand how it works: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Now I can able to share content to Facebook,But it is not appearing in Facebook wall,Is there any thing else?

Comment: Yes I resoled I am using the following code:
view-source:http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/facebook-js-graph-api-post-to-wall/index2.html

Comment: In the part of FB.ui({  }) section...